# Why does ChangeTracker.Load() not load all of my navigation properties?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a collection of entities referenced in my `Company` entity like this

```
public sealed class Company 
{
    private readonly List<CompanyJobCategory> _jobCategories = new();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<CompanyJobCategory> JobCategories => _jobCategories.AsReadOnly();
}

public sealed class CompanyJobCategory
{
    public CompanyJobCategory(int jobCategoryId, Guid companyId)
    {
        JobCategoryId = jobCategoryId;
        CompanyId = companyId;
    }
    
    public int JobCategoryId { get; private set; }
    public JobCategory JobCategory { get; private set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class JobCategory
{
    // the stuff I need is here
}
```

Everything is working fine, but I now have a need to ensure those `JobCategory` navigation properties are available at some point before calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

I grab the entity like this

```
var entry = DbContext.ChangeTracker
    .Entries<Company>()
    .FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Entity.Id == id)!;
```

But can see that for each `entry.Entity.JobCategories`, `JobCategory` is always null (due to how I've initialised the entity)

I thought I could do something like

```
DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Company>().First().Collection(x => x.JobCategories).Load();
```

but that does not populate the child nav props

I also tried setting `IsLoaded` to false before calling `Load()` but it doesn't help

The strangest thing I've noticed is that ocasionally **some of those child entities will be fully loaded if I look inside entry.Collections(x => x.JobCategories)[0].JobCategory** but there is no difference to how I add any of those. How is that possible?

I also tried the following, which seems to load most of the `JobCategory` refs, but still some come through as null - is it possible?

```
entry.Collection(x => x.JobCategories)
    .Query()
    .Include(y => y.JobCategory)
    .Load();
```

Comment: "references another entity called JobCategory" - a *single* `JobCategory` or a collection of `JobCategory`? I assume a collection from reading your Q but it may prove useful making it clearer please.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary `CompanyJobCategory` contains a reference to a single `JobCategory` - it is basically a m2m join table

Comment: The last snippet (with `Query().Include(...).Load()` ) is the intended way to accomplish what you are asking for.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks Ivan, any idea why 1 or 2 of the nav props still are not populated? Mostly it works, but some still come in as null, even though I can see the do reference a real row in the foreign table... It seems impossible though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work

```
// get the entity which is about to be persisted
var entry = DbContext.ChangeTracker
    .Entries<Company>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Entity.Id == id)!;

// select the ids for the referenced entities I need to load
var jobCategoryIds = entry.Entity.JobCategories
    .Select(x => x.JobCategoryId); 

// load them into into DbContext
await DbContext.Set<JobCategory>()
    .Where(x => jobCategoryIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .LoadAsync();
```

Rather than just calling `LoadAsync()` on the tracked collection, I need to load the reference entities I need straight into `DbContext`